# INA226 Vbus voltage reading has a 1.5% error on all measured voltages

Tags: voltage-measurement, texas-instruments

I have an INA226 module with a 0.1 Ohm shunt resistor, here's the schematic:
[image: Aliexpress INA226 module]

Device powered from 3.3V (ESP32 regulator's voltage).

Since I only wanted to test the voltage monitoring function, I applied 0-35V on the Vbus pin.

Here are the measurement results:

```
Set[V]  INA reading[V]
0       0.03
0.5     0.51
1       1.02
1.5     1.53
2       2.03
3       3.05
4       4.06
5       5.08
10      10.15
15      15.23
20      20.3
25      25.38
30      30.46
35      35.53
```

I also tried powering the sensor from an external power supply instead of the ESP32's 3.3V. By varying the Vcc voltage from 3.3V down to 1.8V, the voltage readings remain unaffected. Specifically, when powered with 1.8V, a 30V reading is only 10mV lower compared to when powered with 3.3V.

The RD6006P power supply is quite precise here, at 35V, my UNI-T UT61D+ multimeter reads 35.01V.

I used Rob Tillaart's and Peter Buchegger's Arduino libraries with similar results.

Any ideas where this offset voltage may be coming from?
Thanks

Comment: @CL VBus voltage measuring doesn't use the shunt resistor at all. Check page 1 of INA226 datasheet: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina226.pdf

Comment: How do you measure this voltage?

Comment: @Antonio51 It's stated above:
"I applied 0-35V on the Vbus pin"
It's an I2C device, the measured voltages can be printed on the serial console.

Comment: @Antonio51 DC voltmeter (V) mode, red probe on the Vbus pin, black probe on the GND pin. If you're asking because you think the multimeter is affecting the sensor measurement, well, it's not the case. Multimeter probes only attached when performing the multimeter measurement and even then, the sensor readings are unaffected.

Comment: 0.1 % gain error max and 10 uV offset max ... Don't understand. NB: I have seen some resistors between In+ and Vin+ and In- and Vin- (to limit current to 5mA max, in case of ...).